# Geometric interpretation of sectional curvature in do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Picture below is from 132th page of do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry. I can feel the red line, but I want to prove it. In my view,  it  comes down to prove
$$
\overline\exp_p|_{T_pM} = \exp_p
$$
where $\overline\exp_p$ is the exponential map of $\overline M$, $\exp_p$ is the exponential map of $M$, $T_pM$ is the tangent space of $M$ at $p$.

What I try:  for any $v\in T_pM$, there are
$$
\overline\exp_p(v) = \overline \gamma(1,p,v),~~~~~~
\exp_p(v)=\gamma(1,p,v)
$$
then how to prove  $ \overline \gamma(1,p,v)=\gamma(1,p,v) $ ?

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\gamma$ is a geodesic of $\overline{M}$ that lies in a submanifold $M$ of $\overline{M}$, then it is also a geodesic in $M$ with the induced metric. This follows from the fact that the connection in $M$ is the tangent component of the connection in $\overline{M}$, and since $\nabla_\dot{\gamma}^\overline{M} \dot{\gamma} = 0$, then both the tangent and orthogonal components have to be also zero, therefore $\gamma$ is a geodesic in $M$. In particular, this is true for every geodesic brought by $\overline{\exp}$.

Let $\gamma$ be a geodesic in $M$ with $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\dot{\gamma}(0) = v$. Let $\alpha(t) := \overline{\exp}_p(tv)$. Then, $\alpha$ is a geodesic in $\overline{M}$ with $\alpha(0) = p$ and $\dot{\alpha}(0) = v$ , since $d(\overline{\exp}_p)_0 = Id$. Then, by the previous paragraph, $\alpha$ is a geodesic in $M$ with same initial conditions of $\gamma$. Therefore they are the same by the uniqueness of the geodesic.

The equality of the two exponential maps now follows.